# Converting a timestamp to freshness index

Tags: python-2.7, timedelta

I have a column in dataframe which has article and its publication date (timestamp). I need to use  this information to find out a freshness score of an article.

```
 articleId       publicationDate  
0      581354   2017-09-17 15:16:55  
1      581655   2017-09-18 07:37:51     
2      580864    2017-09-16 06:44:39     
3      581610    2017-09-18 06:30:30     
4      581605    2017-09-18 07:22:24
```

Most recent article should get higher score. Timewindow should be half an hour (2 articles published in half an hour must get same score)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the code below might be redundant but it seems to work:

```
df['score'] = df['publicationDate'] - df['publicationDate'].max()
df['score'] = (df['score'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')).apply(lambda x: (round(x / 30) * 30 + 30) / 30 if x else x).rank(method='max')
```

So you convert timedelta to minutes, then round it to 30, and finally rank that value.
It can also be a one-liner if you please:

```
df['score'] = ((df['publicationDate'] - df['publicationDate'].max()) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')).apply(lambda x: (round(x / 30) * 30 + 30) / 30 if x else x).rank(method='max')
```

Explaination:

`(df['publicationDate'] - df['publicationDate'].max()` - subtract all dates from most recent one

`(df['score'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'm'))` - convert timedelta into minutes

`.apply(lambda x: (round(x / 30) * 30 + 30) / 30 if x else x)` - roundup to 30 minutes excluding most recent timestamp

`.rank(method='max')` rank the results giving upper value to all those that have same rank.

**EDIT**:

To change rank of those older than 2 days you can use this:

```
df['diff'] = (df['publicationDate'] - df['publicationDate'].max()).apply(lambda x: x.days)
df.loc[df['diff']<=-2, 'score'] = 0
```

First line will give you timedelta in whole days, and second one will change rank to `0` where days are less or equal to `-2`.

Comment: Thanks.. But could you pl tell what `(df['score'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'm'))` is doing?

Comment: Sure, it converts the timedelta into minutes.

Comment: If I want to rank only articles published between last 2 days and rest articles be ranked 0  then what could be the workaround?